# What does "Comment" stands for in "function addComment(Comment $comment)"

Tags: php, class, function

i've just seen this strange thing in a tutorial, but cannot figure out what this "Comment" within the variables-brackets stands for. Do you know ?

```
public function addComment(Comment $comment) { ..... }
```

cheers

Comment: Why the hell do people downvote this ? Weird...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means the argument must be an object of the class `Comment`.  If an argument which is not a `Comment` object is passed in, PHP will raise an error.

This feature is called "[type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)".